# How do i keep a clicked navigation button highlighted in css?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

```css
.message-show {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.product-list {
  border: 1px solid #b1b8c9;
  color: $color-grey-light;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    background-color: $color-safron;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="message-show">

  <li v-on:click="displayMsg" @click="getPartingCharges('4')" :class="{ activeListItem }" class="product-list">5-10 </li>

  <li v-on:click="displayMessage" @click="getPartingCharges('10-22')" :class="{  active: isActiveClass,}" class="product-list">10-22 </li>

  <li v-on:click="displayMessage" @click="getPartingCharges('22-27')" :class="{  active: isActiveClass, }" class="product-list">22-27</li>



</ul>
```

I have 3 buttons, like a,b,c. So On clicking of every button i need to show the blue color highlighted and stay over there.

and when if user press different button, then color highlight need to move.

Comment: use a class to add the highlited color and javascript to toggle it

Comment: @КольоПеев If you run the code snippet. i am able to select the particular functionality but the issue is only color highlighting on toggling every button.

Comment: Can you please provide any code snippet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works with Vanilla JavaScript only, I removed the VueJS syntax for better understanding of the solution

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.product-list')

elements.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    elements.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'))
    el.classList.add('active')
  })})
```

```css
.message-show {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.product-list {
  border: 1px solid #b1b8c9;
  color: lightgray;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-list:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="message-show">
    <li class="product-list">5-10</li>
    <li class="product-list">10-22</li>
    <li class="product-list">22-27</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.active{
   background-color: #0095ff;
 }
</style>

<script>
function getPartingCharges(){
  $(":button").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand this question so I'll create 2 CSS solutions:

- If the button has to stay highlighted even if you're not holding the click button, use
  `a:focus { background-color: blue; //or others }`
- Instead, if you want the button to be highlighted **only** when you are holding them clicked use
  `a:active { background-color: yellow; }`
  hope this helps, good luck with your html.

Comment: IF you do not understand questions, always use the comment box to seek more clarity, then proceed with the answer if the author has clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with the required blue styling.
Then add an event listener onClick to addClass('blue-highlight')
When clicked on other button removeClass('blue-highlight')

```
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var current = this;
      for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        if (current != elem[i]) {
          elem[i].classList.remove('blue-highlight');
        } else if (current.classList.contains('blue-highlight') === true) {
          current.classList.remove('blue-highlight');
        } else {
          current.classList.add('blue-highlight')
        }
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  };
}
toggleItem(document.querySelectorAll('product-list'));
```

Something like this:

https://codepen.io/aish_0509/pen/ExmNmvB